# React multiple pages app with different authorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I’m currently trying to build the structure of a react app that I’m working on, i have a home page that any one can see, and a dashboard only users with a specific role can view.

I’m using webpack.
How can i put the project structure to separate different pages and split the application so that it loads only the parts the user need ?

Thanks.

Comment: Look for webpack entry points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack supports multiple entry points: 
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application

You can define them like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    pageOne: './src/pageOne/index.js',
    pageTwo: './src/pageTwo/index.js',
    pageThree: './src/pageThree/index.js'
  }
};
```

Comment: I’m using react router and webpack html pluging, do i have to create different html pages for each entry point ?

Comment: React router will not really work with that as you have to load different js files for different pages. Your only possiblity with that would be react-loadable: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loadable

Comment: It does the same job as lazy feature in react, I’m going to use one single page index.html with html webpack pluging and dynamic imports using lazy feature. Thanks marvin.